# Faker is generating duplicate data when called twice in 2 successive lines (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, cypress, faker

I'm using faker to generate data on my cypress tests, It generates exactly the same data when I call it twice.

Here is my helper Function:

```
export const generateProgram = () => {
    _.cloneDeep(program);
    _.set(program, 'name', faker.random.word());
    _.set(program, 'email', faker.internet.email());
    _.set(program, 'lockDate', moment(faker.date.future()).format('YYYYMMDD'));
    _.set(program, 'lockTime', moment().format('LT'));
    return program;
```

And here is my test case:

```
it.only('Should search for an existing program successfully', () => {
               const program1 = schoolSample.generateProgram();
               const program2 = schoolSample.generateProgram();
               const programs = [program1, program2];
               cy.log(JSON.stringify(programs))
               cy.log(JSON.stringify(program1))
               cy.log(JSON.stringify(program2))
               app.pages.School.expandToViewPrograms(newSchool.name);
               programs.forEach(program => {
                   cy.log(JSON.stringify(program));
                   app.pages.School.clickAddNewProgram();
                   app.pages.School.createProgram(program);
                   app.pages.School.clickSave();
                   cy.wait(1500);
               });
               practicumfit.commons.Search.search(program2.name);

               assert.school.programListIsFilteredCorrectly(program2.name);
           });
```

And here is the log results, it generates exactly the same data which results in failing my test.
[image]

Trying to make sure that the problem isn't any other place in the code, I just tried this code snippet and it worked correctly.

```
const programA = schoolSample.generateProgram();
cy.log(JSON.stringify(programA));
app.pages.School.clickAddNewProgram();
app.pages.School.createProgram(programA);
app.pages.School.clickSave();
const programB = schoolSample.generateProgram();
cy.log(JSON.stringify(programB));
```

While the below one generates duplicate data

```
const programA = schoolSample.generateProgram();
const programB = schoolSample.generateProgram();
cy.log(JSON.stringify(programA));
app.pages.School.clickAddNewProgram();
app.pages.School.createProgram(programA);
app.pages.School.clickSave();     
cy.log(JSON.stringify(programB));
```

Comment: Faker generates all the data once before your tests start running. Im sure if you put the test cases in different `describe` blocks it should regenerate the data more than once.

Comment: @ItsNotAndy
The helper function generates different data in different tests, My problem is with the first 2 lines in the added test case. This is the only place where the data gets duplicated.

Comment: `generateProgram` cloning an object called `program` but not assigning it to anything and mutating then returning the original object seems suspicious to me. Also what do the following functions do: `clickAddNewProgram`, `createProgram` and `clickSave`?

Comment: @Wing
`clickAddNewProgram`, `createProgram` and `clickSave` are just functions that. perform UI actions. 

for `generateProgram()`, I'm using it as helper to create an object with defined structure that's why I cloneDeep the original object, change its values and return it back to use it in other tests.

Comment: In regards to `generateProgram`, I'm saying you are cloning the `program` object but then you don't do anything with the cloned object – you don't assign the result of `cloneDeep` to anything. Instead you mutate the original object you cloned from by using `set` and then return the original object – not the cloned object. Not certain this is the cause of your issue but it is suspicious to me. I think you'll need to post the code for `clickAddNewProgram`, `createProgram` and `clickSave` because they are having some influence on behaviour but we won't know what it is unless you share the code.

Comment: @Wing 
It worked fine after changing generateProgram() by assigning the cloned object to a new one, modifying it then returning it back. Thank You 

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by changing the helper function to below one

```
export const generateProgram = () => {
    const modifiedProgram  = _.cloneDeep(program);
    _.set(modifiedProgram, 'name', faker.random.word());
    _.set(modifiedProgram, 'email', faker.internet.email());
    _.set(modifiedProgram, 'lockDate', moment(faker.date.future()).format('YYYYMMDD'));
    _.set(modifiedProgram, 'lockTime', moment().format('LT'));
    return modifiedProgram;
}
```